# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' in Jenkins using pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, python-requests, pyinstaller, dsl

I am currently using a Jenkins pipeline to automate the build, test, and delivery phase of my application. I am attempting to use the `requests` library in `Python3`. In PyCharm my program works perfectly fine however after completing the delivery stage I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'` error upon running the `.exe`. I have attempted to hidden-import the requests module in the pyinstaller script ran through my Jenkins file and have also tried upgrading/downgrading pyinstaller and requests. Am I missing something? Here is the code to the delivery stage of my pipeline.

```
stage('Deliver') { 
    agent any
    environment { 
        VOLUME = '$(pwd):/src/'
        IMAGE = 'cdrx/pyinstaller-windows:python3'
    }
    steps {
        dir(path: env.BUILD_ID) { 
            unstash(name: 'compiled-results') 
            sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} 'pyinstaller -F pollut_api.py --hidden-import requests -y'" 
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            archiveArtifacts "${env.BUILD_ID}/dist/*" 
            sh "docker run --rm -v ${VOLUME} ${IMAGE} 'rm -rf build dist'"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you found any solution for above code ?